# what is the purpose of module in IOS interface builder?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I'm new to iOS, I found a textfield called `Module` in identity inspector of interface builder. What is the use/purpose of this field? I searched in web but didn't find satisfactory answer. Can any one please explain?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need to use a custom class that its source file is embedded in .framework file for example.

let's say you've added a cocoapod library that gives you a custom UIView subclass and you want to add it inside your storyboard. So you will have to "import" that library to IB and then select the custom view.

You can think of it as the "import Library" line for the IB.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's *Module* as defined by the [Swift programming language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID4) and will define which module to load the class from:

> A module is a single unit of code distribution—a framework or
>   application that is built and shipped as a single unit and that can be
>   imported by another module with Swift’s import keyword.